# expandbale listView childItem is not showing

Tags: java, android

i am trying to create expandable listView when i run app header list showing but when i click on header list child item is not showing and app gone crashed so plz help me

My app LogCat-

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.gulab.expendablelistview.myAdapter.getChildrenCount(myAdapter.java:33)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.refreshExpGroupMetadataList(ExpandableListConnector.java:563)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.expandGroup(ExpandableListConnector.java:688)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:693)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:653)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

---

MainActivity-

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    myAdapter myAdapter;
    HashMap <String,List<String>> child_items;
    List<String> parent_items;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        parentListData();
        childListData();
        ExpandableListView expandableListView= (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

        myAdapter=new myAdapter(this,parent_items,child_items);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);


    }

    public void parentListData() {
        parent_items=new ArrayList<>();
        parent_items.add("Action Movies");
        parent_items.add("Romantic Movies");
        parent_items.add("Comedy Movies");
    }

    public void childListData() {
        child_items=new HashMap<>();
        List<String> action=new ArrayList<>();
        action.add("aa");
        action.add("aa");
        action.add("aa");

        List<String> romantic=new ArrayList<>();
        romantic.add("aa");
        romantic.add("aa");
        romantic.add("aa");

        List<String> comedy=new ArrayList<>();
        comedy.add("aa");
        comedy.add("aa");
        comedy.add("aa");

        child_items.put(action.get(0),action);
        child_items.put(romantic.get(1),romantic);
        child_items.put(comedy.get(2),comedy);

    }

}
```

---

myAdapter-

---

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<String> parent_items;
    HashMap<String,List<String>> child_items;
    public myAdapter(Context context, List<String> parent_items, HashMap<String, List<String>> child_items)  {
        this.context=context;
        this.parent_items=parent_items;
        this.child_items=child_items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parent_items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child_items.get(parent_items.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return parent_items.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child_items.get(parent_items.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String text= (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view,parent,false);
        }
        TextView textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_text);
        textView.setText(text);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String text= (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view,parent,false);
        }
        TextView textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_text);
        textView.setText(text);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: child_items.put(action.get(0),action);
child_items.put(romantic.get(1),romantic);
child_items.put(comedy.get(2),comedy);   this is mistake =)

Comment: parent_items.get(0); parent_items.get(1); parent_items.get(2) must be keys